# WPF Core - Connection Strings inside App.config Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, connection-string, visual-studio-2019, wpf-core

Upon facing the said issue even followed the simple walkthrough at [Connection Strings - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings) but found out that while **hardcoding** the connectionstring as:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;");
}
```

leads to success, using the recommended approach of inserting an App.config file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BloggingDatabase"
         connectionString="Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and updating the main code to:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloggingDatabase"].ConnectionString);
}
```

is not successful, and following error being faced while carrying out **migration**:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Intro.BloggingContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\<...FileLocation...>\AppDbContext.cs:line 14
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What could be the reason behind the same?

Thanks in advance for your reviewing and replying.

Comment: Did you check this properties `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloggingDatabase"].ConnectionString`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings available in .NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0)

Comment: If you are referring to use of the namespace **System.Configuration** I have done the same plus the said property being completely being referred to as the following does not resolve the said problem:
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloggingDatabase"].ConnectionString);

Comment: **Strange!!!** Upon using the index technique i.e. like:

**optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);**

is successful!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the only satisfying answer to a mirror question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909207/cannot-add-appsettings-json-inside-wpf-project-net-core-3-0).

App.Config is not a correct choice for Connection Strings for **WPF Core**. It's rather an appsettings.json file successful enough in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Strange!!! Upon using the index technique i.e. like: optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString); is successful! – Faraz Ahmed Qureshi Mar 28 at 17:06

Indeed this works